# Como eu faço pra executar uma função enquanto a interface do tkinter está rodado rodando?

Tags: python, tkinter

Estou tentando mudar a cor de fundo do label por um comando de voz usando a biblioteca speech_recognition mas não consigo rodar o código dela ao mesmo tempo da interface do tkinter

```py
from tkinter import *
import testeFala

def menu():
    print(testeFala.mic())

def iniciarTela():
    escolhas = Frame(None)
    escolhas.pack(comand = menu())

    fonte = ("Times","15")

    cursiva = Label(escolhas, text="CURSIVA", font=fonte, width="20", height="20",foreground = "white", background= "red")
    cursiva.pack(side = LEFT)

    forma = Label(escolhas, text="FORMA", font=fonte, width="20", height="20",foreground = "white", background= "red")
    forma.pack(side = LEFT)

    matematica = Label(escolhas, text="MATEMÁTICA", font=fonte, width="20", height="20", foreground = "white", background= "red")
    matematica.pack(side = LEFT)
    
    root = escolhas
    root.mainloop()

iniciarTela()
```

tentei fazer isso mas a funçao do comando de voz é chamada antes da tela aparecer

Comment: Bem-vindo ao Stack Overflow em Português. Se você estiver com dificuldade em alguma parte específica, considere compartilhar o seu código, e diga o que já tentou fazer e qual está sendo a dificuldade, assim facilita a reconhecer a sua dificuldade e assim você aumenta as suas chances em conseguir uma boa resposta. Não deixe de ler o [Manual de como NÃO fazer perguntas](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5486/100416) para ter uma experiência melhor por aqui.

Answer (score -2):

consegui resolver o problema usando a biblioteca threading colocando a função do reconhecimento nela.
Segue a modificações do codigo

```
    
from tkinter import *
import testeFala
import threading

escolhas = Frame(None)
escolhas.pack()

fonte = ("Times","15")

cursiva = Label(escolhas, text="CURSIVA", font=fonte, width="20", height="20",foreground = "white", background= "red")
cursiva.pack(side = LEFT)

forma = Label(escolhas, text="FORMA", font=fonte, width="20", height="20",foreground = "white", background= "red")
forma.pack(side = LEFT)

matematica = Label(escolhas, text="MATEMÁTICA", font=fonte, width="20", height="20", foreground = "white", background= "red")
matematica.pack(side = LEFT)

def menu():
    while 2:
        frase = testeFala.mic()
        if(frase == "cursiva"):
            cursiva.configure(bg="green")
        elif(frase == "forma"):
            forma.configure(bg="green")
        elif(frase == "matemática"):
            matematica.configure(bg="green")

root = escolhas
threading.Thread(target=menu).start()
root.mainloop()
```